# FlowPlayer and IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net, video, flowplayer, mov

Have just setup FlowPlayer to play some videos on a new web app i'm working on.  Works perfectly well in Safari (iPad), however, it seems i am not getting any audio in IE.

Code:

```
<div id="videoContainer" style="display: none; text-align: center;">
   <a id="player2" style="display:block; margin:0px auto; width:600px; height:400px"></a>
</div>
```

and JS:

```
  var player2 = document.getElementById("player2");
  player2.href = "http://server/Media/" + videoName;
  $f(player2, "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", {
     clip: {
        autoPlay: true
     }
  });
```

Video plays fine, but no audio.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: For anybody else with the issue - had the MOV re-encoded by the creator using a different audio encoding and it fixed the issue.  Not too sure what encoding was used, but FlowPlayer didn't like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that explorer doesnt have the correct codec installed?

Comment: You might be right, will give this a go a little later and get back to you.  Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a codec issue since videos play audio fine in <object> and <embed>

Comment: Close, the issue was the audio encoding used.  Not quite an IE thing, but it was not compatible with FlowPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I understood your problem BUT:
Maybe the problem is with autoplay option when parent tag is hidden? Try to execute play() function manually when you show #videoContainer tag.

Comment: The video does play, just without the audio.